# Booting Ubuntu Desktop for the first time without monitor and accessing it through SSH

Tags: boot, networking, server, ssh, sd-card

I do not have a monitor, keyboard, or mouse plugged into my Raspberry Pi 4. I am able to flash Ubuntu Server to an SD card and boot the Raspberry Pi for the first time and then simply SSH into it.

```
ssh ubuntu@192.168.1.10
```

I want to try and flash Ubuntu Desktop instead. When I do this and turn on the Raspberry Pi for the first time I am unable to SSH into it:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.10 port 22: Connection refused
```

Is it possible to adjust one of the files on the SD card card so that SSH will be enabled for setting up Ubuntu Desktop? Once I get access I was going to install XRDP and then use remote desktop to use the machine.

Comment: How are you '*flash*' Ubuntu Desktop on your pi?   Are you installing `ubuntu-desktop` on the server image? running `desktopify`? or starting again with a new image?  Ubuntu Desktop by default usually only provides the `openssh-client ` so you can `ssh` out, but not in (servers provide `openssh-server` as remote access is usually expected of a server).

Comment: The Ubuntu Desktop installer image does not include an SSH Server. Instead, try installing the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package onto Ubuntu Server.

Comment: @guiverc I am using Raspberry Pi Imager to flash the SD card with Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 for ARM processors. I am aware that if I had a monitor, mouse, and keyboard I would simply go through the initial setup and then run apt install openssh-server. Is there a way I can have SSH enabled without doing this? For Ubuntu server it works great since SSH is enabled by default. But Ubuntu Desktop I don't think it is.

Comment: @user535733 So you are saying it isn't possible unless I flash some other image?

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop as I & @user535733 said, doesn't include `openssh-server` by default, only the client, as desktop users want generally to access remote machines, but not the other way around (it's also more secure for a desktop to not allow remote access). You need to add it, or you can use `desktopify` to modify a Ubuntu Server model into a desktop (adding `ubuntu-desktop` doesn't go all the way on a *pi*, `desktopify` does everything).  Your choice, you can edit the media directly on a PC and add it, or attach keyboard, or start from server, ....